# Query array on model codeigninter

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter, models

I am a student who learns CodeIgniter, I have a school assignment about the database, I create a project, and run query in my model just like this.

```
class Send_model extends CI_Model{        
   function hello(){ $table = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM (`tbl1`) LEFT JOIN `tbl2` ON `tbl2`.`id` = `tbl1`.`child_id` LEFT JOIN `tbl3` ON `tbl3`.`id` = `tbl1`.`child_id` ");
    foreach($table->result() as  $row){
    $modbus[]= $row->modbus;
    $data []= $row->data;
    $alert[]= $row->alert;
    };
        $param0 = '&'.$modbus[0].'='.$data[0].':'.$alert[0]; 
        $param1 = '&'.$modbus[1].'='.$data[1].':'.$alert[1];
        $param2 = '&'.$modbus[2].'='.$data[2].':'.$alert[2];
        $param3 = '&'.$modbus[3].'='.$data[3].':'.$alert[3];
        $param4 = '&'.$modbus[4].'='.$data[4].':'.$alert[4];
        $param5 = '&'.$modbus[5].'='.$data[5].':'.$alert[5];
        $param6 = '&'.$modbus[6].'='.$data[6].':'.$alert[6];
        $param7 = '&'.$modbus[7].'='.$data[7].':'.$alert[7];
        $param8 = '&'.$modbus[8].'='.$data[8].':'.$alert[8];
        $param9 = '&'.$modbus[9].'='.$data[9].':'.$alert[9];
        $param10 = '&'.$modbus[10].'='.$data[10].':'.$alert[10];
        $param11= '&'.$modbus[11].'='.$data[11].':'.$alert[11];
        $param12 = '&'.$modbus[12].'='.$data[12].':'.$alert[12];
        $param13 = '&'.$modbus[13].'='.$data[13].':'.$alert[13];
        $param14 = '&'.$modbus[14].'='.$data[14].':'.$alert[14];
        $param15 = '&'.$modbus[15].'='.$data[15].':'.$alert[15];
        $param16 = '&'.$modbus[16].'='.$data[16].':'.$alert[16];
        $param17 = '&'.$modbus[17].'='.$data[17].':'.$alert[17];
        $param18 = '&'.$modbus[18].'='.$data[18].':'.$alert[18];
    $sent = $param0.$param1.$param3.$param4.$param5.$param6.$param7.$param8.$param9.$param10.$param11.$param12.$param13.$param13.$param14.$param15.$param16.$param17;

    return $sent;
}
```

my controller just like this

```
class Send extend CI_Controller{
function data ()
{ 
$this->load->model('send_model');
$send = $this->model->send_model->hello();
echo $sent;
}
}
```

- i have a problem,if tbl1 add data  then i have to write adding code to my script
- can anyone  help me to simplify this code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because you're hard-coding to send only 19 rows of data by creating 19 `$param` variables. In a dynamic condition, you may have an empty record-set or hundreds of records. Modify the structure of your `foreach` loop to the following:

```
$param = array();
foreach($table->result() as  $row){
$param[] = '&'.$row->modbus.'='.$row->data.':'.$row->alert;
} 
return $param;
```

Hope it answers your question.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i modify my script as your suggestion, but i have an error result  "array",when i call my controller in a browser

Comment: It is because you're using `echo` to display the array. Use `var_dump` to check if the array is returning values and then you can apply your logic of displaying the array the way you want to.
PS: please mark my answer by clicking on the tick mark next to it. Thank you.

Comment: finally it works, and learn much from you , i'm very grateful to you